# Error when running simple python script

Tags: python

When I run the following:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'before exit'
    sys.exit(0)
```

The output is:

```
before exit
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I don't know why the exception occurs, but it was suggested that it could be an improper installation of Python. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to fix this? I am running Windows 7 x64, but with an x32 install of everything.

Comment: Sounds like a bad installation. I tried it on my Win 7 x64 system with Python 2.7 32bit, and it worked fine.

Comment: I was hoping there was some way of going about this without reinstalling everything =/ It use to work fine, then I played around with things. There's a lot to reinstall.

Comment: also works on linux Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48)

Comment: may be a sleep function could help ?

Comment: [Runs on IDE One (python 2.7.2)](http://ideone.com/72Nvp)

Comment: which version of python are you using? Cpython, stackless python?

Comment: I can run everything; it just gives me that output at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that suggest you have a bad python install (an exception thrown running something so simple is a clear indication of corruption). But reinstalling need not be painful.

Here's what I would do.

First, rename your python directory (on windows its something like c:\python2.x)

Next, install fresh copy of python (be sure it's the same version you already were running)

Finally, copy the Site-packages folder from previous installation into the new install.